# org.hibernate.MappingException - Scala Many-to-many

Tags: scala, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a Spring Data JPA project setup with the following two entity classes in Java.

```
@Entity
class Book {

  ...

  @Size(min = 1)
  @ManyToMany
  private List<Author> authors;

   ...
}

@Entity
class Author {

  ...

  @Size(min = 1)
  @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "authors")
  private List<Book> books;

  ...
}
```

They work fine.

Now, I convert the project into a Scala project and those two entity classes as

```
@Entity
case class Book private[example](...,
                                @BeanProperty @ManyToMany @Size(min = 1) authors: java.util.List[Author]){

  ...
}

@Entity
case class Author private[example](...) {

  ...

  @BeanProperty
  @Size(min = 1)
  @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "authors")
  var books: java.util.List[Book] = _
}
```

And I get an exception

```
caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.List, at table: book, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(authors)]
```

What is missing?

Comment: not sure why you use many to many.. where is the join table?

Comment: In the Java version, DB schema is generated based on the Java entity class definition.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using java.util.List with the parameter Author use the scala List with the parameter:

```
case class Book private[example](...,
                                @BeanProperty @ManyToMany @Size(min = 1) authors: List[Author])
```

This should fix the error.

Comment: First, based on my reading, all data types used in Spring Data need to be Java data types, but not Scala ones. Second, I try using the Scala List data type and the collection field is treated as a column in the book table of the database, but not in a cross reference table.